# Multiple regression models in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression

If I have data that include:

The gender variable gets the value "1" for a woman and "0" for a man.

The variable hours is the average number Of weekly working hours

The variable salary is the monthly salary.

And the educ.n variable is education according to the following coding:
High school to high school - 1, bachelor's degree - 2, master's degree - 3
Doctorate - 4, Other - 5

First, I needed to do The simple model in which wages
The monthly is the dependent variable and the working hours are the independent.

so, I wrote -

```
mod1<- lm(salary ~ hours , data = salary_data)
```

Now, I need to add  the gender and education variables to the model.
these variables are dummy. so, how I add them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `lm()` does all the work as long as you specify that the variable is a factor (with `as.factor()` e.g.). Since gender is dichotomized you do not have to do this as it is already dichotomized (dummy).

This code should work fine :

```
data$educ.n = as.factor(data$educ.n)
mod1<- lm(salary ~ hours + educ.n + gender, data = salary_data)
```